# Parse.com equivalent to sql query

Tags: android, sql, join, parse-platform, nosql

I want to know how can I achieve the following SQL query on parse,

e.g. assume we have 2 tables/classes in our DB: User, Profile with example values in brackets.

```
User
- email(tt@tt.com)
- Name(tt)

Profile
 -email(tt@tt.com)
 -age(23)

Sql query,
select User.email,User.name,Profile.age from User 
JOIN Profile on User.email = Profile.email
Where User.email = 'tt@tt.com'
```

The resulting recordset would be `"tt@tt.com,tt,23e"`. 
Now, if I want to make the same thing with Parse, or better, how can I achieve this??
I read about these structures but I don't know if they apply to this case and how to use them. I'm developing in Android
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you create 2 classes? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Yes, Actually in place of profile it is UserImages, where one user can have many images

Comment: Check my answer. Make sure to change the field names.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pointers to `_Users` on your Class `Profile` best method would be this one :

```
var Profile = Parse.Object.extend("Profile");
var query = new Parse.Query(Profile);
query.equalTo("email", request.params.email);
return query.first().then(null, function(error) {
    return Parse.Promise.error('Sorry, this profile was not found.');
}).then(function(profile) {
    profile.get('_User').fetch().then(function(user) {  
        console.log(
            'name : ' + user.get('name') + ' ' + 
            'age : ' + profile.get('age')
        );
    });
});
```

Note for `profile.get('_User')` your pointer's name may change and not be `_User`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.
In User class, create a Pointer to Profile. Then you can query from User class to get Profile.

```
ParseQuery<User> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
parseQuery.whereEqualsTo("emai", "youremail@mail.com");

parseQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<User>() {
  public void done(User user, ParseException e) {
    if (e != null) {
      Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
      return;
    } 
    Profile profile = (Profile) user.get("profile");
  }
});
```

Comment: is there other way other than this as, in Profile there is a column called user(pointer to User table)

Comment: yes, i have a pointer to user class..but i want to query on User and get age from profile...

Comment: Why don't you query on Profile then get other information from user?

Comment: the actual name is UserPhoto with columns(photo(file),profile_image(boolean),user(pointer to User))
as i said there can be many image for one User, and want to get  photo according to one user whose profile_image is true